# How to make a DataTable in a Positioned inside of a Stack scrollable

Tags: flutter, dart

I want to be able to scroll the DataTable() to view all of the table rows.

Here's my UI:

[image]

And here's the code.

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.grey[200],
      body: Stack(
        overflow: Overflow.visible,
        children: <Widget>[
          // Header & Overlap
          Positioned(
            ...
            child: CustomHeaderContainer(),
          ),
          Positioned(
            ...
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              height: 50,
            ),
          ),
          //

          // TODO: Make the table below scrollable
          Positioned( //*3
            ...
            child: Container( //*2
              color: Colors.white,
              width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width * 0.9,
              child: DataTable( //*1
                columns: [
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Name')),
                  DataColumn(label: Text('Year')),
                ],
                rows: [
                  DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(Text('Dash')),
                    DataCell(Text('2018')),
                  ]),
                  DataRow(cells: [
                    DataCell(Text('Gopher')),
                    DataCell(Text('2009')),
                  ]),
                  ...
                ],
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
```

*Here's what happens if I try to add a SingleChildScrollView:

1. DataTable: No scroll & no error
2. Container: No scroll & no error
3. Positioned: Error, Incorrect use of ParentDataWidget & No scoll

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using a custom scroller with sliver list

```
CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
          SliverList(delegate: SliverChildListDelegate([
            ...children
          ])),
        ],
      )
```